# WPF Application Menu disabled when the focus is on a Textbox and wont work until app restart

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

I am having a problem with the AppMenus in my sample WPF application.

Window2.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWpfApp.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWpfApp"
    Name="RootWindow"
    Title="Window2" Height="600" Width="800">
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+N" Command="ApplicationCommands.New" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=TopMenu}" />
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+F1" Command="{x:Static local:TopMenu.ShowHelp}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=TopMenu}" />
</Window.InputBindings>    
<DockPanel>
    <local:TopMenu DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="TopMenu" />
    <ContentControl>
        <local:Home x:Name="MainContent" />
    </ContentControl>
</DockPanel>
```

TopMenu.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleWpfApp.TopMenu"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWpfApp"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+N" Command="ApplicationCommands.New" />
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+F1" Command="{x:Static local:TopMenu.ShowHelp}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Executed="NewExecuted" CanExecute="NewCanExecute"/>
    <CommandBinding x:Name="HelpCmdBinding" CanExecute="AltHelpCanExecute" Executed="AltHelpExecuted" Command="{x:Static local:TopMenu.ShowHelp}" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.New" />
            <MenuItem Header="E_xit" InputGestureText="Alt+F4" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Help">
            <MenuItem Header="_View Help" InputGestureText="Ctrl+F1" Command="{x:Static local:TopMenu.ShowHelp}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_About" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

TopMenu.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class TopMenu : UserControl
{
    public static RoutedCommand ShowHelp = new RoutedCommand("AltHelp", typeof(TopMenu));

    public TopMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    void NewExecuted(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The " + ((RoutedCommand)e.Command).Name + " command invoked on " + ((FrameworkElement)target).Name);
    }
    void NewCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    void AltHelpExecuted(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The " + ((RoutedCommand)e.Command).Name + " command invoked on " + ((FrameworkElement)target).Name);
    }
    void AltHelpCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }


}
```

Home.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleWpfApp.Home"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="10,37,0,0"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="10,86,0,0"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="10,127,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Run the application. Make sure not to click the Textbox or tab to the textbox. Click the File Menu. The menu is enabled. Check the View Help menu. It is also enabled. When you click you get the message boxes. Everything is good.

But when I click the Textbox, the menus are disabled. I can't get the menus enabled again until I restart the application and don't click the textbox. (Using Gestures still fires the messagebox though). Can someone help me identify the issue? This is driving me crazy for sometime :(

Comment: I got it. I added FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" to the TopMenu usercontrol and it did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Adding FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" to the TopMenu usercontrol did the trick.

Comment: That is /exactly/ what I'm looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this link for some basics on Focus in WPF. It helped me a lot. http://www.julmar.com/blog/programming/part-1-its-basically-focus/

Comment: Cool!  Thank you very much for the detailed information about Focus.  I'll read the article well to know more about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to define the InputBindings in both `Window2.xaml` and `TopMenu.xaml`. A `CommandSource` (like a `KeyGesture`) is defined and added to a `RoutedCommand` once for all.

`RoutedCommand` is the WPF way to separate command's mechanism in four concepts:

1. `Command` is the action to be executed.
2. `CommandSource` is the object which invokes the command (can be a Control or InputGesture).
3. `CommandTarget` is the object that the command is being executed on.
4. `CommandBinding` is the object which maps the command logic to the command.

`RoutedCommands` can be triggered from several `CommandSources`, each `CommandSource` can define its own `CommandTarget` and every `UIElement` on the tree can implement the `Executed` and `CanExecute` event handlers by adding a `CommandBinding` to the `RoutedCommand`.

How it works :

1. When a `CommandSource` triggers the `RoutedCommand`, a `PreviewExecuted` event is tunneling down the `element tree` from the `Window` until the `CommandTarget` object, looking for a `CommandBinding` that handles the event.
2. If the `e.Handled` is not set to `True`, an `Executed` event is bubbling the `element tree` from the `CommandTarget` up to the `Window`,  looking for a suitable `CommandBinding` that handles the event.

What is important here is how the `CommandTarget` is defined. When the `CommandTarget` property of a `CommandSource` is not defined, the Control wich has the focus is the default `CommandTarget`. The magic with `Toolbars` and `Menu` is that they set the `CommandTarget` property of
their children to the control that currently has focus. Technically, they look at the parent, which is the `Window` in your case, and find the most recently focused control in the `Window` **Focus Scope**, which is the `Textbox`. The `ToolBar` and the `Menu` have a separate focus scope.

So what's going on with your code : When the `Textbox` has logical Focus, the `MenuItems` (as a `CommandSource`) are disabled, but if you use the defined `KeyGesture` (Ctrl+N and Ctrl+F1) the commands are executed.

You have defined two `CommandSources` for each `RoutedCommand` :

1. a `KeyGesture` with the `CommandTarget` set to TopMenu. The `Command` directly looks at the target and find the `CommandBinding`. Those `CommandSources` are always enabled then. You hit the keys and the commands execute.
2. a `MenuItem` with the `CommandTarget` not set. It is dynamically set to the focused Control if there is one in the `Window` Focus Scope. Then we have two scenarios :

   - When the `Textbox` is not focused, the `CommandTarget` are not set. So the `Command` looks through all the `element` tree of the `Window` and finds the `CommandBinding` in the TopMenu `UserControl`. So the TopMenu is the `CommandTarget` and the `CommandSource` are enabled.
   - When the `Textbox` is focused, the `CommandTarget` property are set with this `Textbox`. The `PreviewCanExecute` and `CanExecute` events are tunneling and bubbling through the `element tree` between the `Window` and the `Textbox`, but they don't go through the TopMenu `UserControl` because it's not a parent of the `Textbox`. No handlers are found then the `CommandSource` are not enabled.

There are several solutions :

1. The most logic way : define the `CommandBindings` and the `event handlers` in the `Window2` class, because it's the top most parent and because your `Commands` are more like `Window` level commands, it has nothing to do with the UserControl `TopMenu` class.
2. Define manually the `CommandTarget` property of the `MenuItems`. See below.
3. This is what you did, set the Attached Property `FocusManager.IsFocusSope` to `True` for the TopMenu. So when the `Menu` looks at the parent Focus Scope, it doesn't look at the `Window`, it looks at the TopMenu.

Defining the `CommandTarget` Property of the `MenuItems`:

```
<MenuItem Command="New" CommandTarget={Binding RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TopMenu}}}/>
...
<MenuItem Header="_View Help" InputGestureText="Ctrl+F1"
    Command="{x:Static local:TopMenu.ShowHelp}"
    CommandTarget={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
    AncestorType={x:Type local:TopMenu}}}/>
```

Small remark : "ApplicationCommands" is optionnal since there is a converter that finds the right `Command`.

It's good to understand that WPF commands mechanism is good when you need several `UIElement` to define different logic for the same command. Each `UIElement` can execute the `Command` on **itself** the way it needs to.